# unable to call button click more than once

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm working on a project that requires more than one call for single button (more than one click)

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    insert(new object(), new EventArgs());
}
```

But I'm unable to call `insert` more than once.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? and what's the insert function do?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to acheive?

What happens when you try this

```
Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   insert(new object(), new EventArgs());
   insert(new object(), new EventArgs());
```

}

Comment: i want to call the method as far as the user click on the button next(Button2)but it only works for one click

Comment: it is possible to call Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) like any other function, be carefull of indefinate recursion if you do the *not recommanded* option of calling it from within the event handler.  Still not sure what you want to do though, it feels very wrong to fire the event handler twice for one event.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained what you have already tried, but have you tried putting a breakpoint in your  event handler and stepping through what happens? Maybe the button handler is being invoked multiple times but your method prevents it from inserting again. It's hard to say unless you give more information.

Comment: i want to call the method as far as the user click on the button next(Button2)but it only works for one click

Comment: You still haven't said if setting a breakpoint proves that the event handler is only invoked once. How do you _know_ that is only invoked once? What have you tried already to test this?